# database design for sale system

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

In a simple sales sample I have 3 primary tables: Order, Product, Orders_Products:

**Product table**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | A         |
|  2 | B         |
+----+-----------+
```

**order table**

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | total_cost | order_date          | status_id  |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       5 |      25.00 | 2012-02-03 23:30:24 |         1  |
|  2 |       7 |      30.00 | 2012-02-13 18:06:12 |         1  |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

**orders_products table**

```
+----+----------+------------+--------+
| id | order_id | product_id |  cost  |
+----+----------+------------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |         34 |  10.00 |
|  2 |        1 |         25 |  10.00 |
|  3 |        1 |         27 |   2.50 |
|  4 |        1 |         36 |   2.50 |
|  5 |        2 |         75 |  25.00 |
|  6 |        2 |         74 |   5.00 |
+----+----------+------------+--------+
```

*But in my system:*

1. A user adds money into his account then he can spend it
2. Products are services like Product A: user can post 5 Ads so when user post a Ads that 5 become 4 and so on.

How should I design DB for it??

Comment: Hmmm.  Use a data model for a bank rather than a data model for a retailer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you know any article about it?

Comment: I would modify your model just a bit. `products->(id, name, price);` `orders->(id, user_id, date_added, status)` and `order_details(id, order_id, product_id, current_price)`

Comment: Simply add a column `money`to the first table. Update it as the user puts money in his account, and het can't order before `money>0`

Comment: Should there be a quantity column?

Comment: @Strawberry where do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You currently have no table to store customer data. I would strongly advise creating one using an Auto-Increment ID field, a name field and a field to store the money on their account which can be modified when the add money to it or purchase something.

In the Order table, the user_id field should be a foreign key from the Customer table I just told you how to create.

If you want to better understand what you should be doing, I would recommend looking at the [Entity-Relationship Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

I don't entirely understand what your second question is, can you explain it in more detail? Are all the products just a set number of ads that the customer can post?

Comment: thnx for your answer, yes I have Customer table just not mention it for simplicity.
about second question: all products are not like that. one other product is for Premium account that user has privilege to see some content for one month.

Comment: You should have mentioned your customer table, it's pretty important to the functionality of your database. What is your problem then? I can see a lot that I would change with your database design but you haven't said what the actual issue is that you are having and how it is preventing you from doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: I do what @Michel answered in comment and it work perfectly for me :)

Comment: But why on earth would you store the credit a customer has on their account in the Product table?

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right :), I just get the idea from that, I put credit in table "Employer" which is my customer